# IDA Pro - Applying function signatures

Tags: ida, linux, c, elf

I have three files:

1. ELF executable,
2. ELF dynamically linked library (`.so`),
3. C headers file (`.h`) with function signatures and related structures for that library.

#1 imports a number of functions from #2.

Is there a way for me to leverage #3 to automatically apply signatures from #3 to:

1. Imports in #1 in one instance of IDA?
2. Exports in #2 in another instance of IDA?

Answer (score 1):

There are several functions in the SDK, in `typeinf.hpp` or `ida_typeinf.py` that could be of use here, with the python API being much easier to use.

- `parse_decls` - for converting a header file to a til_t type library.

  - this function seems to skip plain function declarations.
  - but does store typedefs by name.
- `parse_decl` - for converting a single declaration to a `tinfo_t` object.

  - this does work for function declarations, but loses the function name.
- `get_named_type` - for looking up a type in the til_t.
- `apply_type` - for applying a type to a function.

So you could either parse the name from the function declaration yourself, and then use `parse_decl` to parse each declaration seperately.

Or you could add `typedef` to the start of each declaration, so ida will store all your declarations, **by name** in a type libary.

Answer (score 0):

Try using File -> Load File -> Parse C Header File (Ctrl+F9). You might need to tweak some things in the header file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this and it did not work. IDA successfully parses the file. I can manually fix function signatures by telling IDA what the arguments are, including custom structure pointers. However, this is very time consuming and feels unnecessary. Is there a way for it to automatically or semi-automatically apply signatures from the header file to functions matched by name?

Comment: Yes. that way is the feature described above. It does not parse complicated C constructs and as mentioned you may need to tweak the file to make it usable by IDA. You can write a script to do that.

Comment: I managed to get first scenario to work using ```tilib```. What changes would I need to make to the header file to get the second scenario to work, i.e. apply function signatures to the library file?